# Using cartopy/shapely to optimize great circle flight paths

Tags: optimization, shapely, cartopy, great-circle

How do I find the great circle that:

1. intersects the most land, or
2. whose longest leg over water is the shortest possible, or
3. intersects the fewest countries?

Is there any app or available code that can answer questions of this type?

Comment: See for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07389v1

Comment: Thank you. I had seen this, but believe there must be a simpler approach.

Comment: This seems like more of an algorithms of even puzzle question which might be a better fit for [math.se] or [puzzling.se]

Comment: But yeah there’s no out of the box tool in cartopy or shapely that do this. This seems like a pretty hard problem with very few applications.

Comment: As some may have guessed from the question, a big application is for initial route planning of aviation circumnavigations. Guinness World Records demands passing through antipodal points. Rather than an algorithmic approach, a brute-force computational one should work; extreme accuracy is not required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.